# How do I modify output markup for system secondary menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to modify the structure of the secondary menu in Drupal 7 that appears when you are logged in. The secondary navigation shows 'My Account' and 'Log Out' links. By default, this renders as:

```
<h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary Menu</h2>
<ul id="secondary-menu-links" class="links inline clearfix">
    <li class="menu-2 first">
        <a href="/user">My account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-15 last">
        <a href="/user/logout">Log out</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code in my theme that is generating this menu is:

```
<?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
    'links'         => $secondary_menu,
    'attributes'    => array(
        'id'        => 'secondary-menu-links',
        'class'     => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
    ),
    'heading'       => array(
        'text'      => t('Secondary Menu'),
        'level'     => 'h2',
        'class'     => array('element-invisible'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

How can I get the following markup outputted instead of what was listed above?

```
<li class="secmenusep"><span>|</span></li>
<li class="menu-2 secnav_account">
    <a href="/user">My account</a>
</li>
<li class="secmenusep"><span>|</span></li>
<li class="menu-15 secnav_logout">
    <a href="/user/logout">Log out</a>
</li>
```

I want the h2 removed, as well as the ul, and add two additional li tags with pipes for separators, and add a unique class to each.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am able to get rid of the h2 by commenting out or removing `'heading' => array(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this custom HTML for your secondary menu by defining your proper theme for links. Because `links__system_secondary_menu` is a theme hook pattern under the form of `[base hook]__[context]`, you can easily implement a theme definition for this secondary menu within your theme by using `YOURTHEME_links__system_secondary_menu`.

Inside the `template.php` of your theme, you can put this code which does exactly what you are asking for:

```
function YOURTHEME_links__system_secondary_menu(&$variables)
{
    $output = '';
    $extra_classes = array(
        'user' => 'secnav_account',
        'user/logout' => 'secnav_logout',
    );

    foreach ($variables['links'] as $item => $link) {
        $classes = array($item);

        if (isset($extra_classes[$link['href']])) {
            $classes[] = $extra_classes[$link['href']];
        }

        $output .= '<li class="secmenusep"><span>|</span></li>';
        $output .= sprintf(
            '<li class="%s">%s</li>', implode(' ', $classes), l($link['title'], $link['href']));
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `YOURTHEME_links__system_secondary_menu(&$variables)` is not working in my case and I can't really explain why. If I then just use `YOURTHEME_links(&$variables)` it's killing my contextual links and I don't know why. Any Idea someone?